# Why is the first Rspec View test ran always the slowest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

Below is my Rspec output and as you can see the first test to run is always the slowest. The first time it was line 18, the second time it was line 27. Could the test be doing any sort of caching?

```
❯ spec spec/views/principals/show.html.haml_spec.rb -p                                                            mbc
Run options:
  include {:focus=>true}
  exclude {:ignore=>true}

All examples were filtered out; ignoring {:focus=>true}

Randomized with seed 25466
..

Top 2 slowest examples (3.47 seconds, 94.4% of total time):
  /principals/show the MINDEX tab a permitted user has tab and a link to the tab
    3.41 seconds ./spec/views/principals/show.html.haml_spec.rb:18
  /principals/show the MINDEX tab a not-permitted user does not have tab or a link to the tab
    0.05673 seconds ./spec/views/principals/show.html.haml_spec.rb:27

Finished in 3.68 seconds (files took 5.98 seconds to load)
2 examples, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 25466

❯ rspec spec/views/principals/show.html.haml_spec.rb -p                                                            mbc
Run options:
  include {:focus=>true}
  exclude {:ignore=>true}

All examples were filtered out; ignoring {:focus=>true}

Randomized with seed 33681
..

Top 2 slowest examples (3.98 seconds, 94.9% of total time):
  /principals/show the MINDEX tab a not-permitted user does not have tab or a link to the tab
    3.73 seconds ./spec/views/principals/show.html.haml_spec.rb:27
  /principals/show the MINDEX tab a permitted user has tab and a link to the tab
    0.25015 seconds ./spec/views/principals/show.html.haml_spec.rb:18

Finished in 4.2 seconds (files took 6.91 seconds to load)
2 examples, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 33681
```

And here are my tests....

```
RSpec.describe "/principals/show" do

  before do
    @principal = FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:principal)
    FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:financial_statement, principal: @principal)
    @financial_statements = @principal.financial_statements.paginate(per_page: 5, page: 1)
    @merchants_index = MerchantsIndex.new(@principal)
    allow(@view).to receive(:current_user).and_return(mock_model(User).as_null_object)
    allow(@view).to receive(:permitted_to?).and_return(true)
  end

  #it "works" do
  #  expect { render }.not_to raise_error
  #end

  describe "the MINDEX tab" do
    context "a permitted user" do
      it "has tab and a link to the tab" do
        expect(@view).to receive(:permitted_to?).with(:read, :merchants_index).twice.and_return(true)
        render
        expect(rendered).to have_selector("a[href='#mindex']")
        expect(rendered).to have_selector("div#mindex")
      end
    end

    context "a not-permitted user" do
      it "does not have tab or a link to the tab" do
        expect(@view).to receive(:permitted_to?).with(:read, :merchants_index).twice.and_return(false)
        render
        expect(rendered).not_to have_selector("a[href='#mindex']")
        expect(rendered).not_to have_selector("div#mindex")
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: it's loading your rails environment

Comment: @Yule, that seems unlikely. If I run the whole test suite the first one ran is always the slowest.

Comment: So when you run you're test suite, the first thing it does is load your environment. Probably with a line such as `require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__` in your spec/rails helper. This only happens once each time you run the suite.

Comment: So the slow bit is that bit running. The other tests then don't need to load in the environment again

Comment: @Yule, That's my understanding. But when I run the whole test suite, it loads the environment, tests start to run....then we hit this file, and because they are in a random order, the first spec of this file always runs slow, then the test suite continues and because I'm running it with the profile flag (-p), it shows the first test of this file as being the slowest. Does that make sense?